# Android: Opens a new input page when I choose inputType as TextPassword in EditText

Tags: android, passwords, android-edittext

I am developing an application where I used login screen. The xml code below:

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_username"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/et_height"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/login_id"
        android:singleLine="true" >     
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/et_height"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true" >    
    </EditText>
```

In this above mentioned code, When I enter the text in first EditText it shows the same screen, But in second EditText, when I used the inputType as textPassword, It is navigating to separate input screen. But as per my requirement it should be same as my first EditText.

Could anyone share your suggestions  please...

Comment: hows navigate the separate screen, i do not think it will navigate separate screen

Comment: When I click the password EditText it opens a white color input box where I can enter the text. It is not similar to my username EditText.